# Batch File to check text files for a string

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, batch-processing

im trying to create a batch file that goes thorugh each text file in a folder and looks for specific words such as "msg" "file" "size" in each line. If those words are found then it sends and me an email.

Im using SQL server to send the email, and im calling the email stored procedure from my batch file like this:

```
set MYDB= yourDBname
set MYUSER=youruser
set MYPASSWORD=yourpassword
set MYSERVER=yourservername
sqlcmd -S %MYSERVER% -d %MYDB% -U %MYUSER% -P %MYPASSWORD% -h -1 -s "," -W -Q "exec yourstoredprocedure"
```

I just need help writing the script which checks for specific words in each line in each .txt file

Comment: You want to look into master.sys.xp_dirtree for getting a directory listing and then you can check for whatever words you want.. you need to be specific with what you need help with.. rather than hoping for a stored procedure that does everything for you..

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try for this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Title Search String into text files
Set "ROOT=%~dp0"
set "String2Search=msg size file"
For %%a in (%String2Search%) do (
    FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%ROOT%\*.txt"') DO (
        (find /I  "%%a" "%%f" >nul 2>&1) && ( Call :FoundString "%%a" "%%f" ) || (  Call :NoFound "%%a" "%%f" )
    )
)   
pause & exit
::*************
:FoundString
echo found %1 on file %2
goto :eof
::*************
:NoFound
echo no string like %1 found on file %2
goto :eof
::*************
```

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions as i cannot comment.I had done a project few years back and i had to do search files with a particular extension and read them to find particular words and do something with them.I remember few things only.I hope it helps you.
To find all txt files:

```
find /home/user/Downloads/etc -name '*txt'
```

To read a whole file and search for "msg" "file" "size":

```
while read -r LINE       
do
grep -i "msg" | grep -i "file" | grep -i "size"
```

to check all in one line 
Or you can do it executing one by one without "pipelining".
P.S I don't have linux installed otherwise I would have checked before posting.Sorry if not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD C:\wherever\your\.txt\files\are\at

FOR /R %%G IN ("*.txt") DO (FINDSTR /I /C:"msg" /C:"file" /C:"size" "%%G" >nul && GOTO match_found)

GOTO no_match

:match_found
ECHO Match found^!

set MYDB= yourDBname
set MYUSER=youruser
set MYPASSWORD=yourpassword
set MYSERVER=yourservername
sqlcmd -S %MYSERVER% -d %MYDB% -U %MYUSER% -P %MYPASSWORD% -h -1 -s "," -W -Q "exec yourstoredprocedure"

:no_match
ECHO No match found^!
PAUSE
```

If the batch file is in the same folder as the `.txt` files you can delete the `CD` line.

If the search should be case-sensitive remove the `/I` option.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy your question as asked, this should suffice:

```
@Echo Off
FindStr /IR "\<msg\> \<file\> \<size\>" "C:\Users\NT-Hero\*.txt">Nul||Exit /B
Rem Your 'match found' commands here
```

If you wanted to also search in sub-directories change the `FindStr` options to `/SIR`. *(See `FindStr /?` for more options).*